# Feed not working

Tags: bug, android-app, android-app-feed

I am using OnePlus One and have recently downloaded the Stack Exchange app, but after logging in using my Gmail ID, the feed page is not showing any data at all.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the app but no difference in that. Whenever I am using this app without an account, all feed data are shown, but as soon as I log in using my Gmail ID, I am again having the same problem of no data in feed page.

What do I need to do to correct this?